# Social Media Aggregator, Global Update via Powershell

Tags: facebook, powershell, twitter

Does anyone know of a way to interface with a Social Media Aggregator using Powershell. For Instance, I would like to update my global status on digsby using Powershell. Digsby would then fan the message out to Facebook, Myspace, Twitter, Etc..

I am open to using any Social Media Aggregator that can do this.. Digsby, Seesmic, Ping.fm TweetDeek, etc..

If any of these programs have a com interface or something like it I'm sure who ever implements this first will have a large gain in users.

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against implementing this against a desktop-application such as Digsby *(unrelated: which, last time I checked, has the ulterior motive of being a malware installer)*.  Instead, interact with a cloud-visible interface so that the users won't be tied to anything being installed on their machines.  Incidentally, there are at least a few libraries already available.

- [PoshTweet](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2008/12/30/introducing-poshtweet---the-powershell-twitter-script-library.aspx): The PowerShell Twitter Script library
- [Facebook Organizer](http://www.powergui.org/entry.jspa?externalID=2034)

I'd think for your goal of having it aggregated to more than one service, Ping.fm integration may be the best bet.  I don't see anyone who has made a PowerShell script for this yet, but seeing as the [Ping.fm API](http://groups.google.com/group/pingfm-developers/web/api-documentation) is also REST based, it would look a lot like the [PoshTweet](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2008/12/30/introducing-poshtweet---the-powershell-twitter-script-library.aspx) implementation.